# Crystal Report Fields

Tags: crystal-reports

How do i prevent a Crystal Report Field from not expanding.

it seems if these are my fields

```
[Column1] [Column2]
XXXXXXXXX YYYYYYYYY
```

when Column1 seemed to have more charaters to display it automatically expand the whole field thus

```
[Column1] [Column2]
XXXXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYY
```

How can I prevent this from happenning?

Comment: Are you seeing this in the Report Designer preview, in a web browser, in an exported file or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the **CanGrow** property for the offending field, found in the properties.

Comment: @Juvil John Soriano: Then check that the borders of the field on the report don't extend beyond where you want them.  That's the only other reason Crystal will not truncate information.

Comment: well i used a guidelines when laying the fields out to prevent overlapping for fields. in the layout it does not extend to the next field.

Comment: @Juvil John Soriano: Are you sure you'll looking at the CanGrow value for the correct field?  IME, that's the only way Crystal allows the field to expand to display more data than the space allows.  It's on a per field basis.